# Remove backslashes from Json String in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework

```
dct_data = json_tour_data.__dict__
tour_data = json.dumps(dct_data)
```

How to remove these backslashes from **json**? Here is my output:

```
"{\"strFileOpenDateAjxKey\": \"2018-01-16 12:40:22.526417\", 
\"strFilePassengerAjxKey\": \"Zahra Walji\", \"strFileOpenMobileAjxKey\": 
\"46464664\", \"strFileOpenDepartmentAjxKey\": \"Finance department\", 
\"strFileOpenAccountCodeAjxKey\": \"CARTZS\", 
\"strFileOpenProfileCodeAjxKey\": \"CARTZS\", 
\"strFileopenOriginalCountryIdAjxKey\": 61, \"blnBoundAjxKey\": 1, 
\"strTransactionCurrencyJsKey\": \"Shillings\", 
\"intCurrencyPrecisionJsKey\": 3, \"strPackageTypeJsKey\": \"PKG\", 
\"strUserNameAjxKey\": \"admin\", \"strPasswordAjxKey\": \"1234\"}"
```

Comment: you can use replace for that `response.replace("\'", '"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  `replace("\'", '"')` for that.

```
     json = '''{\"strFileOpenDateAjxKey\": \"2018-01-16 12:40:22.526417\", 
      \"strFilePassengerAjxKey\": \"Zahra Walji\", \"strFileOpenMobileAjxKey\": 
      \"46464664\", \"strFileOpenDepartmentAjxKey\": \"Finance department\", 
      \"strFileOpenAccountCodeAjxKey\": \"CARTZS\", 
      \"strFileOpenProfileCodeAjxKey\": \"CARTZS\", 
      \"strFileopenOriginalCountryIdAjxKey\": 61, \"blnBoundAjxKey\": 1, 
      \"strTransactionCurrencyJsKey\": \"Shillings\", 
      \"intCurrencyPrecisionJsKey\": 3, \"strPackageTypeJsKey\": \"PKG\", 
      \"strUserNameAjxKey\": \"admin\", \"strPasswordAjxKey\": \"1234\"}'''
newString = json.replace("\'", '"')
print(newString)
```

check from [here](https://repl.it/repls/VillainousRemorsefulSulphurbutterfly)

*that is the output when pressed the run in my side.*
[image: output]

Comment: There is no issue when i am trying from terminal using pdb. but while retrieve the service using the RESTer there is the same issue exists.

Comment: i tried your link (https://repl.it/repls/VillainousRemorsefulSulphurbutterfly). but there is backslashes in out put. like when i try my own terminal using pdb.

Comment: hey.. #krezus my issue solved. Thank you for your answer. i just removed json.dumps(dct_data). because it is already in json format

Comment: This can be solution but not a correct way to do it.

Comment: @RushabhSudame you don't have to vote down even if you think that answer is not the way should be. It might have helped someone and might help again.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is you have to just play with `json.dumps()` and `json.loads()`.

The following is my code which worked:-

```
import json
json_data = {'key1': 'first'}
json_data = json.dumps(json_data)
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'schools':  json.loads(json_data)
}
```

The output of above code is as follows:

```
Response:
{
  "schools": {
    "key1": "first"
  },
  "statusCode": 200
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking your Response object where your parse your `tour_data` variable/dictionary in your views. I originally had the same issue as you but here's what I changed.

Original implementation: `Response(json.dumps(a_dictionary), status=status.HTTP_200_OK)`

to

New implementation: `Response(a_dictionary, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, content_type='json')`

The key things here are:
1. Getting rid of the `json.dumps` conversion method and just pass through a plain python dictionary e.g. see `a_dictionary`.
2. Setting `content_type='json'` on the Response object.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else who might be facing this issue.

simply put:
the original question seems to be taking JSON data (I emphasize, it's already JSON) and rendering it into JSON again.

dct_data = json_tour_data.**dict**

tour_data = json.dumps(dct_data)